# How to run a nohup command present in a variable using ssh?

Tags: shell, ssh, nohup

I am new to Linux. I stored a command in a variable say

```
a="nohup ./startWebLogic.sh &".
```

I need to run this command on remote server along with few other commands. I have tried as follows...

```
ssh user@server << EOF
few shell commands then
eval "$a"
EOF
```

When I run the above script, it doesn't do anything after logging in the remote server, neither it throws me any error, nor it runs the nohup command..my intention is to start the WebLogic on the remote server using nohup...thanks!!

Comment: I did a echo $a after the ssh and was surprised to see that the '&' went missing, I escaped it when declaring a (a="nohup ./startWebLogic.sh \&"). Now when I run the script, it gives me error -sh: nohup: not found

Answer (score 1):

You just can run it so:

```
ssh user@server "$a"
```

The variable `$a` will be expanded and passed to the shell at `server`.

If you want to use <

```
ssh user@server sh -s <<EOF
few shell commands then
eval "$a"
EOF
```

Please note `sh -s` here and that, that I removed the space between `<<` and `EOF`.

Comment: thanks Chubin, but there are few more things I need to do before I execute the $a on the remote server..so I have used the <<EOF and executed few commands and then given the eval $a..

Comment: I've edited my answer. Please check the new version.

Answer (score 0):

Worked with a="nohup ./startWebLogic.sh >> nohup.out 2>&1 &"

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, try create a file **e.g** `a.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
nohup ./startWebLogic.sh &
exit 0
```

and set 
`a="./a.sh"`